# jquery adding class to variable inside if, else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add a class to a variable inside one of my if else statements in a jquery function. I am getting an error x.addclass is not a function. I have tried placing the variable in () and without. It makes no difference.

```
var ideal = document.getElementById( 'ideal_' + id )
var Search = document.getElementById('Search_' + id)

var parent = document.getElementById(+id)
if(ideal){
    parent.addClass('myclass')
}  else if (Search){
   parent.style.background='yellow'
}  else {
   parent.style.background='none'
}
```

Comment: This is not jquery. try `parent.classList.add('myclass')`

Comment: `.addClass()` is a jQuery method to add classes to the selected element and `.classList.add()` is a Javascript way of adding classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a jQuery method, you can call that on a jQuery referenced element.

Try using `classList.add()`:

```
parent.classList.add('myclass');
```